# Cannot select any valid SQL engine on Ec2 for Prestashop

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Hosted Prestashop on AWS EC2  and imported database on AWS RDS and configured app/config/parameters.php file with the RDS credentials still getting the error ...

Did chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/prestashop/app also for giving access rights to Logs Folder

[Error Message of sql engine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpVOp.png)

> Configuration File of Prestashop:

```
'database_host' => 'url of RDS',
'database_port' => '3306',
'database_name' => 'prod db name',
'database_user' => 'production user name',
'database_password' => 'secret key',
'database_prefix' => 'ps_',
'database_engine' => 'InnoDB',  // Tried with mysqli too, still facing error
'mailer_transport' => 'smtp',
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please create a file phpinfo.php at the root of your website with this content:

```php
<?php
phpinfo();
```

You might be missing mysqli extension, you should then run this in command line:

```
yum install php-mysqli
```

Comment: Hi Honey Thakuria, if this answer helped you solve your problem, could you please take a second to accept it to mark this thread as solved? [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)